# How do I join two table on a column and group by on another column

Tags: r, group-by, merge

Lets say I have two franchise of dance schools.

I have two tables. First table tells about students roll no. every

Table 1 =

```
Roll No.    Center ID   Name    Date
1   A   Anna    10/10/2020
1   A   Anna    11/10/2020
1   B   Anna    12/10/2020
2   A   Bella   12/10/2020
2   B   Bella   13/10/2020
3   A   Catty   10/10/2020
```

Table 2 =

```
Roll no.    Center ID   Report
1   A   Did well
1   A   Sick 
1   B   Needs more twist
2   A   Practice required
2   B   Did well
3   A   Needs more practice
```

Result table expected: I want in the result it should pick Center id as A only but Report should be from both the centers

```
Roll no.    Center ID   Report  Name
1   A   Did well ,Sick ,Needs more twist    Anna
2   A   Practice required,Did well  Bella
3   A   Needs more practice Catty
```

Could someone pls help.

Comment: Please post data in `dput` format. Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is a placeholder for the names of your datasets.)

Comment: `CenterID` A has never `Needs more twist`. Is your table expected correct or just an example?

Comment: `Needs more twist` from `Anna` is only a thing of center `B`. Do you really want to have it in center A in the result?

Answer (score 1):

By `dplyr`,

```
t1 %>%
  mutate(Report = t2$Report) %>%
  group_by(Roll_No.) %>%
  summarise(Center_ID = "A",
    Report = paste0(Report, collapse = ', '),
    Name = unique(Name)
    )

  Roll_No. Center_ID Report                           Name 
     <int> <chr>     <chr>                            <chr>
1        1 A         Did well, Sick, Needs more twist Anna 
2        2 A         Practice required, Did well      Bella
3        3 A         Needs more practice              Catty
```

Comment: @TarJae God I forgot `,`. I only `group_by` `Roll_No.` to get `Needs more twist`

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

a <- tribble(
  ~Roll, ~Center, ~Name, ~Date,
  1, "A", "Anna", "10/10/2020",
  1, "B", "Anna", "12/10/2020",
  3, "A", "Catty", "10/10/2020"
)

b <- tribble(
  ~Roll, ~Center, ~Report,
  1, "A", "Dis well",
  1, "A", "Sick",
  1, "B", "Needs more twist",
  3, "A", "Needs more practice"
)

a %>%
  left_join(b) %>%
  group_by(Roll, Center) %>%
  summarise(
    Report = c(Report, Name %>% unique()) %>% paste0(collapse = ",")
  )
#> Joining, by = c("Roll", "Center")
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'Roll'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   Roll [2]
#>    Roll Center Report                   
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                    
#> 1     1 A      Dis well,Sick,Anna       
#> 2     1 B      Needs more twist,Anna    
#> 3     3 A      Needs more practice,Catty
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

With **`dplyr`** package:

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(df1, Report=df2$Report) %>% group_by(Name) %>%
  summarize(RollNo=first(RollNo), CenterID=first(CenterID), Report=paste(toString(Report), first(Name), collapse='  '))
```

Output:

```
  Name  RollNo CenterID Report                               
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>                                
1 Anna       1 A        Did well, Sick, Needs more twist Anna
2 Bella      2 A        Practice Required, Did well Bella    
3 Cathy      3 A        Needs more practice Cathy
```

Answer (score 0):

**update:**
With the hint of @Park many thanks!:
Logic:

1. `left_join` by `RollNo.`
2. `filter`, `group_by` and `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
table1 %>% 
  left_join(table2, by=c("RollNo."="Rollno.")) %>% 
  filter(CenterID.x== "A") %>% 
  group_by(RollNo., CenterID=CenterID.x, Name) %>% 
  summarise(Report = paste(unique(Report), collapse = ", "))
```

output:

```
  RollNo. CenterID Name  Report                          
    <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>                           
1       1 A        Anna  Did well, Sick, Needs more twist
2       2 A        Bella Practice required, Did well     
3       3 A        Catty Needs more practice
```

**First answer:**
We could try this: It is depending on whether `Date` should be considered or not, so you may modify the code:

```
table1 %>% 
  left_join(table2, by=c("CenterID", "RollNo."="Rollno.")) %>% 
  filter(CenterID == "A") %>% 
  group_by(RollNo., CenterID, Name) %>% 
  summarise(Report = paste(unique(Report), collapse = ", "))
```

```
    RollNo. CenterID Name  Report             
    <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <chr>              
1       1 A        Anna  Did well, Sick     
2       2 A        Bella Practice required  
3       3 A        Catty Needs more practice
```